# How do I update state values using Formik and setFieldValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I am trying to write a simple profile page where the user can change their photo, name, username and bio. The fields name, username and bio I keep inside in formik form, because I need to perform some validations on them. Inside the `<Formik>` form I have a button submit which is the following:

```
<TouchableOpacity
                onPress={handleSubmit} //the important part!!!
                title="UPDATE PROFILE"
                disabled={!isValid}
                style={isValid ? styles.buttonStyle : styles.buttonStyleInvalid}
              >
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>UPDATE PROFILE </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

My `handleSubmit` method is outside my `<Formik>` form. It needs to check if the username is taken. I dont want to do such calls to the db every time the user touches the username field, I want to check it only on submit. Here is my method:

```
const submitHandler = async () => {
    //my formik values have been set up correctly
    console.log("checking formik values: ", formRef.current.values);
    //username is part of my state; so I want to update it with the values from the form
    setUsername(formRef.current.values.username.trim());
     //username is with the old value
     console.log("checking if username has been updated: ", username);
    //yet here, when I check the value of the username it is the old value, and the state hasnt been updated
    // so I dont even go inside this if case, because my state hasn't been updated
    if (username !== props.currentUser.username) {
      //do some checks not important
    }
  };
```

Here is my state:

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState(props.currentUser.username); 
const [name, setName] = useState(props.currentUser.name);
const [bio, setBio] = useState(props.currentUser.bio);
```

Here is my `Formik` (I am not including name and bio because it is similar):

```
<Formik
        validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
        initialValues={{ name: name, username: username }}
        onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
          submitHandler();
        }}
        innerRef={formRef}
      >
        {({
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          values,
          errors,
          touched,
          isValid,
          setFieldValue,
          setFieldTouched,
        }) => {
          return (
            <>  
              <TextInput
                value={username}
                style={styles.textInputStyle}
                name="username"
                keyboardType="twitter"
                placeholder="Username"
                onChangeText={(val) => {
                  setFieldValue(
                    "username",
                    val
                      .normalize("NFD")
                      .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
                      .replace(/\s+/g, "_")
                      .replace(/[^a-z0-9_]/gi, "")
                  );
                  setFieldTouched("username", true, false);
                  setUsernameError(null);
                }}
                onBlur={handleBlur("username")}
                value={values.username}
                autoCapitalize="none"
              />
              {errors.username && touched.username && (
                <Text style={styles.error}>{errors.username}</Text>
              )}
              {usernameError ? (
                <Text style={styles.error}>{usernameError}</Text>
              ) : null}
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={handleSubmit}
                title="UPDATE PROFILE"
                disabled={!isValid}
                style={isValid ? styles.buttonStyle : styles.buttonStyleInvalid}
              >
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>UPDATE PROFILE </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
```

My question: How do I set my `username` correctly, so that my `handleSubmit` method performs the checks correctly? I tried updating it using `setUsername(formRef.current.values.username.trim());` obviously, it doesnt work, so Im guessing I should call it from `onChangeText` method? But then I am not using properly `setFieldValue` I guess?

Comment: In your submit handler, calling `setUsername(formRef.current.values.username.trim());` is a) asynchronous, so will not change the state immediately b) pointless anyway, because if the form is set up properly, there's no need to set anything

Comment: @ChrisG when you say "pointless anyway", you mean I need to work with `formRef.current.values.username` instead of `const [username, setUsername] = useState(props.currentUser.username); `?

Comment: No, the opposite. All form data should be stored in your state already, given that the state is continuously updated while the form is filled. When you type into the username field, `onChangeText` should put the current .value into the state, so it's already in there when you submit the form.